# Add a new field to array elements in a foreach PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I have this variable:

```
$families = array(
    array(
        'expand'      => '',
        'family_id'   => 'AAER',
        'active'      => true,
        'description' => 'Wall Art',
        'group_id'    => 5
    ),
    array(
        'expand'      => '',
        'family_id'   => 'EERR',
        'active'      => true,
        'description' => 'Personalised Mugs',
        'group_id'    => 4
    ),
);
```

And I want add to my $families items a field called 'href', like this:

```
$families = array(
    array(
        'href'        => 'http://mipage/wall-art/AAER',
        'expand'      => '',
        'family_id'   => 'AAER',
        'active'      => true,
        'description' => 'Wall Art',
        'group_id'    => 5
    ),
    array(
        'href'        => 'http://mipage/personalised-mug/EEER',
        'expand'      => '',
        'family_id'   => 'EERR',
        'active'      => true,
        'description' => 'Personalised Mugs',
        'group_id'    => 4
    ),
);
```

To do this I iterate $families in a foreach loop:

```
foreach($cat['families'] as $cat_fam) {
    $cat['families'][]['href']  = 'http//mysite/'.str_slug($cat_fam).'/'.$cat_fam['family_id'];
}
```

But this not works for me.

How can I make this?

Comment: You need to specify how it is not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to repalce empty `[]` with the specific `key`. For this update `foreach` block to get `key` of the element and use that inside `foreach` loop.

`$cat['families'][$key]` which points to individual element of the families array.

Like this,

```
foreach($cat['families'] as $key=>$cat_fam) {
    $cat['families'][$key]['href']  = 'http//mysite/'.str_slug($cat_fam).'/'.$cat_fam['family_id'];
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/636898

Answer (score 1):

just iterate over the array, and add a key `ahref`

```
 $newArray= array();
 foreach($families as $innerArray){
   $innerArray['ahref']='YOUR LINK HERE'; 
   $newArray[] = $innerArray;
 }

$families = $newArray ;//if you want to update families array
```

Comment: It should be `$newArray[] = $innerArray;` instead.

Comment: @AlokPatel yes, typo, actually I quickly tested the output on my machine and updated it here..

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
$href = array('href'=>'http://mipage/wall-art/AAER');
$combined_array = array_combine($families[0],$href);
```

Don't tested but you can try or modify as per your use

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

I think you also forgot to add index `description` in your `str_slug` call.

```
foreach($cat['families'] as &$cat_fam) {
    $cat_fam['href'] = 'http://mysite/'.str_slug($cat_fam['description']).'/'.$cat_fam['family_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Liek this :

```
array_walk($cat['families'], function(&$family){
   $family['href'] = 'http//mysite/'.str_slug($family).'/'.$family['family_id'];
 });
```

note the $family variable is passed by reference.